# Pandas -- new column as sum of values from x rows of different column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

searching for quick solution to my task related to pandas DataFrame cratering new column from a formula run above different column. I would put example here:

Core:

```
import pandas

def Proximity(row):
    Proximity_value = 1
    return Proximity_value

Order = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
O_Value = [3 ,10 ,8 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,9 ,7 ,1 , 5]

Data_df = pandas.DataFrame(zip(Order, O_Value), columns=["Order", "O_Value"])
print(Data_df)

   Order  O_Value
0      1        3
1      2       10
2      3        8
3      4        1
4      5        2
5      6        3
6      7        9
7      8        7
8      9        1
9     10        5
```

New Column should be:

```
   Order  O_Value   New_Column
0      1        3   0
1      2       10   7
2      3        8   -2
3      4        1   -7
4      5        2   1
5      6        3   1
6      7        9   6
7      8        7   -2
8      9        1   -6
9     10        5   4
```

Simply logic is to prepare a formula which will always do current_row["O_Value"] - previous_row["O_Value"]

Comment: Additionally the formual might be also differnet --> to count multiple previous lines not only one

Comment: `Data_df['New_Column'] = Data_df['O_Value'].diff().fillna(0, downcast='infer')`

Comment: Of `Data_df['New_Column'] = Data_df['O_Value'] .sub(Data_df['O_Value'].shift()).fillna(0, downcast='infer')`

Comment: Hello this works, than kyou